# Custom scrollbar only shows up after reloading

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, scrollbar

I'm currently working on a piece of code which customs the scrollbars of my website by using only CSS and Webkit. At the moment, I'm aware that it only works on Chrome/Chromium.

My problem is, my scrollbar isn't visible until I refresh the page. We can scroll and all, but we can't see it.

CSS:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 15px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: white;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: lightgreen;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Does anyone know why I have this problem, and how I can solve it ?

Thanks ~